# Wordpress Admin Menu, display an other name for the top level

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a different menu title. Like "Goto" should be "More" but if you click on it it should still go to the first.

[image]

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_pages');
function my_menu_pages(){
    add_menu_page('More', 'More', 'manage_options', 'my-menu', 'edit.php?post_type=goto' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Goto', 'Goto', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=goto' );
    add_submenu_page('my-menu', 'Gallerys', 'Gallerys', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=join' );
}
```

Comment: Remove admin menu script and then again add script. Maybe cache issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to achieve the above -

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fix_admin_menu', 999 );
function fix_admin_menu(){
    global $submenu;
    if ( ! isset( $submenu['my-menu'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    unset( $submenu['my-menu'][0] );
}
```